# Linq Left-Join DefaultIfEmpty, check if null while initializing?

Tags: c#, linq

In a left-join linq query such as:

```
var sales = await (
    from order in conxtext.orders
    join customerJoin in conxtext.customer on order.customerid equals customerJoin.customerid into
        customerGroup
    from customer in customerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        OrderNumber = order.ordernumber,
        CustomerName = customer == null ? "" : cumstomer.customername
    }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

how can we check for null on a keyless table? I'm getting this error message using the above linq query:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot translate the '==' on an
> expression of entity type 'customer' because it is a keyless entity.
> Consider using entity properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

With EF Core you do not have to check entity for `null` before accessing property. Instead of that correct result:

```cs
var sales = await (
    from order in conxtext.orders
    join customerJoin in conxtext.customer on order.customerid equals customerJoin.customerid into
        customerGroup
    from customer in customerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        OrderNumber = order.ordernumber,
        CustomerName = cumstomer.customername ?? ""
    }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```